# CSS3 preserve internal box shadow with child elements?

Tags: css

Have a look at this:
http://jsfiddle.net/6Yq8b/78/

Is there a way I can preserve a Div's internal box shadow when child elements move outside its boundaries? In the given link, what happens is the child element ("toplid") is obscuring the internal box shadow on the top of the box...

Ideas?

Comment: I guess the only way of doing this is to add another element to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/6Yq8b/84/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simulate the box shadow on the `#toplid` element by applying an inset box shadow on it:

```
#toplid {
  box-shadow: inset 0 80px 42px -2px black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6Yq8b/86/

---

**EDIT:**

You already have box-shadow set on that element, so use multiple box-shadows:

```
#toplid {
  box-shadow:0 0 20px -2px black, inset 0 80px 42px -2px black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6Yq8b/87/

Comment: Your solution is most interesting, but it creates another problem... The Child element does not conform to the parent element's border-radius, and results in the curvy inner borders not showing for the top half of the design... But yes, I'd have to agree with you, logically your solution makes sense...

Comment: @Abhishek the box-shadow before the comma is your original one, the one after the comma is the new, inset box-shadow to simulate the box-shadow on the `.btn` element. If you need the inset shadow to be more rounded, give the top of `#toplid` rounded corners: `border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0`. The actual corners are hidden and the shadow is brought down into visibility, so that should simulate the parent element nicely. http://jsfiddle.net/6Yq8b/102/